# Laravel5.1 how to do a multi-condition query with if clause

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am a beginner, and currently creating a laravel project which needs multi-condition query like this:

**View layer sample**

[image]

Each of these three conditions could be blank.

If one is blank, the corresponding controller should not add 'where clause' when querying the db.

I know in java, I can apply if clause to this like:

```
String sql = "select field from table where 1 = 1";

if(a!=null&&!a.isEmpty())
  sql+=" and a = '"+a+"'";

then execute sql......
```

But in laravel, how do i address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Laravel **[Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)** instead of direct `sql`, let say you have model called `Test` :

```
$wheres = [];
$q = new Test();

if( !empty($input_1) )
      $wheres['table_field_1'] = $input_1;

if( !empty($input_2) )
      $wheres['table_field_2'] = $input_1;

....

foreach ( $wheres as $k => $v )
{
    if ($k == 'userName')
         $q = $q->where('userName', 'LIKE', '%'.$userName.'%');
    else
         $q = $q->where($k, $v);
}

return $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); //And you could use eloquent functions
```

And that will generate query as :

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE table_field_1=$input_1 AND table_field_2=$input_2... 
ORDER BY 'created_at'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: eh... another question...when it comes to fuzzy query, I write like `$wheres['userName'] = ['LIKE' => '%'.$userName.'%'  ];` but it won't work properly... any ideas on this one?